How do I insert my image into the Kivymd button?
I want to insert my image into the button, but I get an error when there is a Users element in my image path. Is it possible to prescribe the path in some other way so that there are no errors?




from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.gridlayout import MDGridLayout

class TestApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        layout = MDGridLayout(spacing=30, cols = 3, padding = 200)
        btn1 = MDRectangleFlatButton(text="", icon="C:\Users\Alena\Desktop\icon")
        btn2 = MDRectangleFlatButton(text="")
        btn3 = MDRectangleFlatButton(text="")
        layout.add_widget(btn1)
        layout.add_widget(btn2)
        layout.add_widget(btn3)
        return layout
TestApp().run()





Also, my images are in the same folder as my project.
When I enter only the name and extension of the image into the path, it also does not output it to me, although without errors.

Try to change your code to the following:
path_img = "icon.png"
btn1 = MDRectangleFlatButton(text="", icon=icon_path)

One problem could be the missing file extension.
If it is a JPG, use icon.jpg of course.
If you want to specify the entire path, it should look like this so that it is interpreted correctly.
path_img = r"C:\Users\Alena\Desktop\icon.png"


Simply specify the path from the root directory in the required button's icon parameter if it has an icon parameter.
Buttons with an icon parameter

MDIconButton
MDFloatingActionButton
MDRoundFlatIconButton
MDRectangleFlatIconButton
MDFillRoundFlatIconButton


Sample Code
For example if you have your project structure like this:
MyProject
|--> main.py
|--> assets
    |--> images
        |--> yourimage.png
    |--> fonts

You'll define the path of the image file anywhere in the .kv files or main.py file like this:

.kv files

MDIconButton:
    icon:"assets/images/yourimage.png"


main.py file

btn1 = MDRectangleFlatIconButton(text="Icon Button", icon="assets/images/yourimage.png")


Overall Modified Code:

Declarative python styles

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatIconButton, MDRectangleFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.gridlayout import MDGridLayout
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.screenmanager import MDScreenManager

class SampleScreen(MDScreen):
    pass

class SampleLayout(MDGridLayout):
    pass

class TestApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.manager_screens=MDScreenManager()

    def build(self) -> MDScreenManager:
        layout = SampleLayout(spacing=11, cols = 3, padding = ("9dp","9dp","9dp","9dp"))
        btn1 = MDRectangleFlatIconButton(text="Icon Button", icon="icon.png")
        btn2 = MDRectangleFlatButton(text="Button")
        btn3 = MDRectangleFlatButton(text="Button")
        layout.add_widget(btn1)
        layout.add_widget(btn2)
        layout.add_widget(btn3)
        screen=SampleScreen(name="sample screen")
        screen.add_widget(layout)
        self.manager_screens.add_widget(screen)
        return self.manager_screens

if __name__=="__main__":
    TestApp().run()


Declarative KV styles

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.gridlayout import MDGridLayout
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivy.lang import Builder

class SampleScreen(MDScreen):
    pass

class SampleLayout(MDGridLayout):
    pass
AppKV='''
SampleScreen:
    SampleLayout:
        cols:3
        padding:"9dp","9dp","9dp","9dp"
        spacing:"11dp"

        MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
            icon:"icon.png"
            text:"Icon Button"

        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text:"Button"

        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text:"Button"
'''

class TestApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

    def build(self) -> None:
        return Builder.load_string(AppKV)

if __name__=="__main__":
    TestApp().run()

I hope your problem is solved with utmost clarification.
